# Cannot find OpenGL headers

Tags: xcode, opengl

I programming an app for the Iphone that uses a 3d object loader. the code of this loader is uses:

`#include <OpenGL/glu.h>`

the compiler is telling "no such file or directory", but I can see the file "glu.h" inside the OpenGL.framework under "External libraries & frameworks".

I am using Xcode 3.2.1

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, there was a wrong import a couple lines of code before, which for some reason cause the compiler to scream at that line...

Answer (score 3):

There is no glu.h in OpenGLES.framework.
But someone created a replacement from the MESA sources:
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-glu/